# Control flow for a while loop with post increment

Tags: java, while-loop

I am not able to figure out how the following code snippet prints 13 as an output. As far as I can see, the while condition should keep looping as `i` is always less than `10` in this case. I tried debugging but couldn't it figure out. Can someone please explain?

```
public class WhileCondition2 
{
   public static void main(String... args)
   {
       int i = 10;
       while (i++ <= 10) 
       {
           i++;
       }
       System.out.print(i);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using **post** increment

```
while (i++ <= 10) { // i will be incremented after evaluating i and do comparaison with 10
      i++; 
}
```

You can use the **pre** increment instead of post increment

```
while (++i <= 10) { // i will be incremented before comparaison
      i++; 
}
```

And the value of `i` will be `11`.

Comment: Thanks for making me understand by explaining pre and post increment example

Comment: But thats not the answer why you end up in 13. It's one of the reasons. Doesn't matter, thats how it works here.

Answer (score 14):

First iteration :

```
  while (i++ <= 10) { // i++ returns 10, so condition is true, i becomes 11
      i++; // i becomes 12
  }
```

Second iteration :

```
  while (i++ <= 10) // i++ returns 12, so condition is false, i becomes 13
```

Therefore the final value of `i` is 13.

Comment: Worth noting that `while(++i <= 10)` can be done and will output 11 as the increment is done before the check.

Answer (score 3):

After `i` becomes equal to `10`, it increments once after the checking and `i` becomes `11`. Then the increment in the loop body happens making `i = 12`. At last the condition is checked where `i = 12` and as expected it turns out to be false. But the increment in the condition section will happen never the less. That is why it prints `13`.

Answer (score 2):

1. You set `i` to `10` would output `10`
2. your loop `while i` is less or equals `10`
3. You do increment after `i++` this means the conditions `i <= 10` is first inspected and then the increment is done output `11`
4. it then enters the loop because `i` was `10` when starting the loop and is now `11`, and get's then incremented to `12`, would print `12`
5. the loop is again going in the case. `i = 12` which is more then `10`, loop ends but your `i++` is still done after the condition failed, `i`  is now **13**

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing i once in the while statement and once in the loop itself, you should do one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the reason the output is 13 is as follows

the stating value of i is 10.

when it enters the while loop i++ <= 10  is true as i == 10 and enters the loop, but before it enters the loop i is incremented to 11 due to the post increment operator.

Once in the loop i is incremented again to 12 again with the post increment operator that is in the loop.

Next the i is tested again in the while(i++ <= 10) and is false as i is 12. but before it exits the loop it is again incremented by the post increment operator that makes it 13.

and this is what is output to the java console window,

The thing to remember with this is even when the while loop condition is false it will still increment  the i value.

Hope this helps.